# ReacJs: how to use state variable of one module to another module

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to ReactJS, I am trying to use city_name variable in another module and not able to find, please help me with this

```
    import { useState } from "react";

    const SearchCity = (props) => {
      const { type = "text", placeHolder = "scarch...", name,} = props;
      const [city_name, setCityName] = useState("");
      return (
        <div className="flex border-2 border-gray-200 rounded">
          <input
            class="px-4 py-2 w-80 text-black take-input"
            type={type}
            name={name}
            placeholder={placeHolder}
            onChange={(e) => setCityName(e.target.value)}
          />
          <button
            className="px-4 text-white bg-gray-600 border-l">
            Search...
          </button>
        </div>
      );
    };

    export default SearchCity;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just send city_name as prop and destructure it.

suppose you have one component  `<Home/>` and you have to pass city_name in home component.

```
     // here sending data as prop

     <Home city_name = {city_name}/>
     
     // Recive data 
      const home = ({city_name}) => {
         <div>
         </div>

 }
```

Comment: No, I want to export "city_name" from child component to parent component

Comment: you can send data using props or read about context api  https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#gatsby-focus-wrapper